# How to get the value of one of the key-value pairs of JSON in JavaScript？

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of gid in JavaScript

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data); √
alert(JSON.stringify(data['responseJSON']['gid'])); ×
```

I tried to use it like this but I got an error.

I found a lot of answers but still can't get the value I need.

```js
{
  "form": {},
  "files": [{}],
  "filenames": ["timg.jpg"],
  "filescount": 1,
  "extra": {},
  "response": {
    "success": true,
    "msg": "image url after upload",
    "gid": 81
  },
  "reader": {},
  "jqXHR": {
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "{\"success\":true,\"msg\":\"image url after upload\",\"gid\":81}",
    "responseJSON": {
      "success": true,
      "msg": "image url after upload",
      "gid": 81
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK"
  }
}


alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

I want to get the value of gid (81)，but it is not use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ouhre! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Here is a way to get the value of 'gid'.

```
let json = {
  form: {},
  files: [{}],
  filenames: ["timg.jpg"],
  filescount: 1,
  extra: {},
  response: { success: true, msg: "image url after upload", gid: 81 },
  reader: {},
  jqXHR: {
    readyState: 4,
    responseText: '{"success":true,"msg":"image url after upload","gid":81}',
    responseJSON: { success: true, msg: "image url after upload", gid: 81 },
    status: 200,
    statusText: "OK"
  }
};

alert(json.jqXHR.responseJSON.gid)
```

You can check this out live at this Codesandbox, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-sutherland-kqmwb), or read more about handling JSON and Objects in Javscript, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)!

Comment: Thank you very much,I didn't expect to spend so much time on this simple question.

Comment: If I helped solve your answer please select my answer as being the one that solved it! I would highly recommend the MDN docs that I linked above, they are super helpful to keep open while writing JS :)

Comment: I am sorry,It shows that Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.But your answer is indeed the best in my heart.